# What is the best way to join two Pandas dataframes on a date, given one naive date and one tz aware datetime as strings in each dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, join

The first dataframe looks like the following

```
df1.tail(10)
Out[8]: 
             date            home_team            away_team
65070  2022-11-29  Philadelphia Flyers   New York Islanders
65071  2022-11-29  Nashville Predators        Anaheim Ducks
65072  2022-11-29        Winnipeg Jets   Colorado Avalanche
65073  2022-11-29       Calgary Flames     Florida Panthers
65074  2022-11-29    Vancouver Canucks  Washington Capitals
65075  2022-11-29    Los Angeles Kings       Seattle Kraken
65076  2022-11-30  Toronto Maple Leafs      San Jose Sharks
65077  2022-11-30      Ottawa Senators     New York Rangers
65078  2022-11-30    Detroit Red Wings       Buffalo Sabres
65079  2022-11-30   Chicago Blackhawks      Edmonton Oilers
```

and the date field has not been manipulated yet so it remains a string.

```
df1.dtypes
Out[10]: 
date         object
home_team    object
away_team    object
dtype: object
```

The second dataframe looks like the following:

```
df2.head(5)
Out[11]: 
                            game_id            home               away  
0  5852b18718643aa437344891e62dea6e  Buffalo Sabres  Detroit Red Wings   
1  5852b18718643aa437344891e62dea6e  Buffalo Sabres  Detroit Red Wings   
2  5852b18718643aa437344891e62dea6e  Buffalo Sabres  Detroit Red Wings   
3  5852b18718643aa437344891e62dea6e  Buffalo Sabres  Detroit Red Wings   
4  5852b18718643aa437344891e62dea6e  Buffalo Sabres  Detroit Red Wings   

                   date  
0  2022-10-31T23:00:00Z  
1  2022-10-31T23:00:00Z  
2  2022-10-31T23:00:00Z  
3  2022-10-31T23:00:00Z  
4  2022-10-31T23:00:00Z
```

```
df2.tail(5)
Out[15]: 
                                game_id                home             away  \
45930  3cfc76eb156254d9fa5584be3442636e  Chicago Blackhawks  Edmonton Oilers   
45931  3cfc76eb156254d9fa5584be3442636e  Chicago Blackhawks  Edmonton Oilers   
45932  3cfc76eb156254d9fa5584be3442636e  Chicago Blackhawks  Edmonton Oilers   
45933  3cfc76eb156254d9fa5584be3442636e  Chicago Blackhawks  Edmonton Oilers   
45934  3cfc76eb156254d9fa5584be3442636e  Chicago Blackhawks  Edmonton Oilers   

                       date  
45930  2022-12-01T02:30:00Z  
45931  2022-12-01T02:30:00Z  
45932  2022-12-01T02:30:00Z  
45933  2022-12-01T02:30:00Z  
45934  2022-12-01T02:30:00Z
```

and also has a string for the date field, but this one comes UTC aware with the time as well as date.

I want to join these dataframes using home_team -> home, away_team->away, date->date.  I have been unable to find a way after many permutations of merge and merge_asof and datetime/date objects with and without tz awareness that properly solves the issue that becomes apparent in the tail of df2.  Those UTC times resolve to the day prior in their respective time zones.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

and then merge.